Why is it that galaxies tend to form large-scale "sheet" and "filament" structures?
I recently picked up a book on physical cosmology, and the first couple of chapters make frequent reference to the development of large-scale "sheet" and "filament" structure. Nowhere, unfortunately, does it appear to be described why or by what means those specific structures form (as opposed to other shapes). I've tried searching around online and in other texts, and the best answers I've found simply state that these shapes form due to gravitational collapse. This answer isn't quite satisfying enough for me.
Why do these particular shapes form as a consequence of gravitational collapse? I understand that it is due to initial density perturbations and a resulting uneven distribution of matter, however it isn't clear to my why such small perturbations naturally lead to sheet and filament shapes. I know that we can run numerical simulations and get as output these structures, however I'm hoping for something more immediately comprehensible.
Why don't we observe this on smaller scales? I'm not knowledgeable on the topic, however I cannot think of any smaller-scale cosmological/astrophysical "objects" that naturally collapse in the same way to sheet or filament shapes (all examples I can think of (e.g., planetary rings and systems) that fall roughly along planes as I understand it do so under the force of very different kinds of processes). Presumably this is simply because the density perturbations relative to the scale are insufficient, and small-scale forces (e.g., angular momentum) have a stronger effect?

First on small scales dark matter halos formed. Then we have galaxies and after that, clusters. The structure of our universe is formed bottom up. And CDM is a sufficient criteria for that to happen. I think filament and sheet are just generic results of very weak gravitational collapse on large scale. On small scale the gravitational collapse is strong so you see stars and galaxies which feature spherical symmetry. You can simulate a very sparse, uniform dust with a small density perturbation and very weak gravitational interaction. Then the typical structure you get from this many-body simulation should be filaments and sheet. Not a specialist, just from physical intuition.

CDM = Cold Dark Matter
